# How to extract everything before the first space?

Tags: r, gsub

```
charvct <- c("amc rebel sst","amc ambassador dpl","amc hornet","amc gremlin" ,"amc 1212")
```

is my vector.

I want to get result as

```
"amc","amc","amc","amc","amc".
```

My Code is :

```
y <- gsub("amc*[A-z][0-9]","amc",charvct)
```

But output is same as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match the 'amc' followed by word boundary (`\\b)`) followed by zero or more (`*`) alpha numeric characters along with the space (`[[:alnum:] ]`) and replace it with `"amc"`

```
sub("amc\\b[[:alnum:] ]*","amc", charvct)
#[1] "amc" "amc" "amc" "amc" "amc"
```

Or capture 'amc' as a group (`(amc)`) and in the replacement we provide the backreference (`\\1`)

```
sub("(amc)\\b[[:alnum:] ]*","\\1", charvct)
```

---

Based on the vector in the comments, we match one or more punctuation characters along with space (`[[:punct:] ]+`) followed by characters until the end of the string (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`).

```
sub("[[:punct:] ]+.*", '', v1)
#[1] "amc" "bcd" "xyz" "amc" "amc" "dfz"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("amc rebel sst","bcd ambassador dpl","xyz hornet",
                             "amc gremlin" ,"amc 1212(a)" ,"dfz+2")
```

Comment: Suppose I want improve upon the code that you suggested instead of only amc,if i have the following: "amc rebel sst","bcd ambassador dpl","xyz hornet","amc gremlin" ,"amc 1212(a) ,"dfz+2")
If my o/p is expected as "amc" "bcd" "xyz" "amc" "amc" "dfz"

Comment: @Rprogr Sorry, didn't see your comments..  I updated the post with the new vector.